# list shift in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog, failure-slice

The following code results in an infinite loop with an eventual "Out of Local Stack" error Basically I am decrementing the value of GX until it is the same as MX.
Sample input [[m,g,b],[w,w,w]],Path

```
wallBlock('w').
wallBlock('b').
item('f').
item('p').
item('m').
item('u').
item('6').
item('r').
item('g').
anyCell(Cell) :- 
    wallBlock(Cell).
anyCell(Cell) :-
    item(Cell).


ghostPathing(Maps, Path) :-
    append(Maps, NewMap), 
    length(Maps, N), 
    findGhost(NewMap, N, GX, GY), 
    findPacman(NewMap, N, MX, MY),
    moveGhost(NewMap, N, MX, MY, GX, GY, Path).

/*FINDS THE COORDINATES OF THE GHOST W=row X=column*/
findGhost(NewMap, N, X, Y) :-
    findGhostSpot(NewMap, S),
    X is floor(S / N) + 1,
    Y is (S mod N) +1 .

findGhostSpot(['g'|_], 0) :-
    print('Found Ghost. ').
findGhostSpot(['r'|_], 0) :-
    print('Found Ghost. ').
findGhostSpot(['6'|_], 0) :-
    print('Found Ghost. ').
findGhostSpot([_|Tail], S) :-
    findGhostSpot(Tail, S1),
    S is S1+1 .

/*FINDS THE COORDINATES OF THE GHOST W=row X=column*/
findPacman(NewMap, N, X, Y) :-
    findPacmanSpot(NewMap, S),
    X is floor(S / N) + 1,
    Y is (S mod N) + 1.

findPacmanSpot(['m'|_], 0) :-
    print('Found Pacman. ').
findPacmanSpot([_|Tail], S) :-
    findPacmanSpot(Tail, S1),
    S is S1+1 .

/* Base Case, Ghost is on the Pacman*/
moveGhost(_, _, X, Y, X, Y, []).

/*IF PACMAN AND THE GHOST ARE IN THE SAME COLUMN*/
moveGhost(NewMap, N, MX, Y, GX, Y, ['u'|Rest]) :-
    itemNext(NewMap, CN, Z),
    item(Z),
    moveGhost(NewMap, N, MX, Y, X, Y, Rest),
    GX is X + 1,
    MX < GX,
    CN is ((X * N) + Y).
moveGhost(NewMap, N, MX, Y, GX, Y, ['d'|Rest]) :-
    itemNext(NewMap, CN, Z),
    item(Z),
    moveGhost(NewMap, N, MX, Y, X, Y, Rest),
    GX is X - 1,
    MX > GX,
    CN is ((X * N) + Y).

/*IF PACMAN AND THE GHOST ARE IN THE SAME ROW*/
moveGhost(NewMap, N, X, MY, X, GY, ['l'|Rest]) :-
    itemNext(NewMap, CN, Z),
    item(Z),
    moveGhost(NewMap, N, X, MY, X, Y, Rest),
    GY is Y + 1,
    MY < GY,
    CN is ((X * N) + Y).
moveGhost(NewMap, N, X, MY, X, GY, ['r'|Rest]) :-
    itemNext(NewMap, CN, Z),
    item(Z),
    moveGhost(NewMap, N, X, MY, X, Y, Rest),
    GY is Y - 1,
    MY > GY,
    CN is ((X * N) + Y).

itemNext([Cell|_], 0, Cell) :-
    item(Cell). 
itemNext([First|Rest], CN, Cell) :-
    anyCell(First),
    itemNext(Rest, N, Cell),
    CN is N + 1.
```

because it is a 2d array the append turns it into 1d and the arithmetic in the NextCell takes the lenght of a row and finds the coordinates of the adjacent cell and returns the value of that cell. The ghost cannot move in that direction if the cell is a 'w' or 'b'. you can assume Maps is SQUARE!

Comment: If GX is a free variable, you receive "< /2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated." so GX is X+1 must be written before MX < GX.

Comment: @joel76 when i do this, i get an infinite loop with an eventual local stack overflow.

Comment: for example, MX=3, Y=3, GX=4, Y=3

Comment: OK, there is a design problem. You should post more codes.

Comment: @joel76 this is the entirety of the code that i have so far. it only works if the pacman and ghost are in the same row/colum when it is finished, but would like it to work wherever the ghost is.

Answer (score 1):

(I assume that your question is why your program loops.)

To localize the reason for the non-termination of your program, I have inserted goals **`false`** into your program. Since the remaining program (**failure slice**) does not terminate, also your original program does not terminate. You need to fix something in the remaining visible part. Or, to put it differently: As long as the current fragment remains unchanged, the problem will persist! And as a minor remark, better avoid `print/1` goals in a pure program as yours is.

For more, see tag [failure-slice](/questions/tagged/failure-slice)

```
?- ghostPathing([[m,g,b],[w,w,w]],Path), false.


item('f') :- false.
item('p') :- false.
item('m').
item('u') :- false.
item('6') :- false.
item('r') :- false.
item('g').

anyCell(Cell) :- false,
    wallBlock(Cell).
anyCell(Cell) :-
    item(Cell).

ghostPathing(Maps, Path) :-
    append(Maps, NewMap), 
    length(Maps, N), 
    findGhost(NewMap, N, GX, GY), 
    findPacman(NewMap, N, MX, MY),
    moveGhost(NewMap, N, MX, MY, GX, GY, Path), false.

/*FINDS THE COORDINATES OF THE GHOST W=row X=column*/
findGhost(NewMap, N, X, Y) :-
    findGhostSpot(NewMap, S),
    X is floor(S / N) + 1,
    Y is (S mod N) +1 .

findGhostSpot(['g'|_], 0) :-
    print('Found Ghost. ').
findGhostSpot(['r'|_], 0) :- false,
    print('Found Ghost. ').
findGhostSpot(['6'|_], 0) :- false,
    print('Found Ghost. ').
findGhostSpot([_|Tail], S) :-
    findGhostSpot(Tail, S1),
    S is S1+1 .

/*FINDS THE COORDINATES OF THE GHOST W=row X=column*/
findPacman(NewMap, N, X, Y) :-
    findPacmanSpot(NewMap, S),
    X is floor(S / N) + 1,
    Y is (S mod N) + 1.

findPacmanSpot(['m'|_], 0) :-
    print('Found Pacman. ').
findPacmanSpot([_|Tail], S) :- false,
    findPacmanSpot(Tail, S1),
    S is S1+1 .

/* Base Case, Ghost is on the Pacman*/
moveGhost(_, _, X, Y, X, Y, []) :- false.

/*IF PACMAN AND THE GHOST ARE IN THE SAME COLUMN*/
moveGhost(NewMap, N, MX, Y, GX, Y, ['u'|Rest]) :- false,
    itemNext(NewMap, CN, Z),
    item(Z),
    moveGhost(NewMap, N, MX, Y, X, Y, Rest),
    GX is X + 1,
    MX < GX,
    CN is ((X * N) + Y).
moveGhost(NewMap, N, MX, Y, GX, Y, ['d'|Rest]) :-  false,
    itemNext(NewMap, CN, Z),
    item(Z),
    moveGhost(NewMap, N, MX, Y, X, Y, Rest),
    GX is X - 1,
    MX > GX,
    CN is ((X * N) + Y).

/*IF PACMAN AND THE GHOST ARE IN THE SAME ROW*/
moveGhost(NewMap, N, X, MY, X, GY, ['l'|Rest]) :-
    itemNext(NewMap, CN, Z),
    item(Z),
    moveGhost(NewMap, N, X, MY, X, Y, Rest), false,
    GY is Y + 1,
    MY < GY,
    CN is ((X * N) + Y).
moveGhost(NewMap, N, X, MY, X, GY, ['r'|Rest]) :- false,
    itemNext(NewMap, CN, Z),
    item(Z),
    moveGhost(NewMap, N, X, MY, X, Y, Rest),
    GY is Y - 1,
    MY > GY,
    CN is ((X * N) + Y).

itemNext([Cell|_], 0, Cell) :-
    item(Cell). 
itemNext([First|Rest], CN, Cell) :-
    anyCell(First),
    itemNext(Rest, N, Cell),
    CN is N + 1.
```